# How to query for old files in CarrierWave?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file-upload, carrierwave

I know that I can keep old files after an uploader is updated:

```
class AvatarUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  configure do |config|
    config.remove_previously_stored_files_after_update = false
  end
end
```

But how can I query for those old files? Assuming someone updates their avatar, the old file stays, is there a way to show the old files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Carrierwave doesn't track old files for you, so if you want this feature you're going to have to implement it yourself. You may have some luck with a gem like [paper_trail](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail).